# Change the background color of active button angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this piece of code in order to highlight the color of the currently active page button.

```
<li ng-repeat="pageNumber in pages track by tracker(pageNumber, $index)" 
    ng-class="{active :pagination.current == pageNumber, disabled : pageNumber == '...' }">
        <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pageNumber)">{{ pageNumber }}</a>
</li>
```

**see the image of buttons**

[image: see the image of buttons]

How can I change the color of the active button?

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is incorrect. try this

```
  ng-class="{'active' :pagination.current == pageNumber}"
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  
  $scope.pagination = {
      current: 2
    };

  $scope.pages = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
  
  $scope.setCurrent = function(pageNumber){
       $scope.pagination.current = pageNumber;
 
    }
  
});
```

```css
.active{
    background-color:green;
  }
li {
    display: inline-block;
}

li > a{
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px 8px;
}

li > a:hover{
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
     <li ng-repeat="pageNumber in pages"  ng-class="{'active' :pagination.current == pageNumber }">
        <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pageNumber)">{{ pageNumber }}</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `active` class in single quotes

```js
angApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

angApp.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  
  $scope.pagination = { current: 2 };

  $scope.pages = [1,2,3,4,5];
  console.log($scope.pages);
  
});
```

```css
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding:5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-right:5px;
    
}

li>a{
    color:black;
}

.active-button{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
     <li ng-repeat="pageNumber in pages"  ng-class="{'active-button' :pagination.current == pageNumber }" ng-click="pagination.current = pageNumber">
        <a href="" >{{ pageNumber }}</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: with that code i am able to see blue color for the current page button ,i need to change that color to green .thanks in advance

Comment: @RamveerSingh you can create a class named active-button insted of active, .active-button{ color:green; }

Comment: @RamveerSingh if u r problem got solved or not, pls inform me

Answer (score 0):

With ng-class, your applying a concrete CSS class according to an expression. In your case, if it's the current page it applies the `active` style

So, you should look for `active` style in your CSS files and check there the corresponding color.

Answer (score 0):

you have Error in your Syntax try below code

```
<li ng-repeat="pageNumber in pages track by tracker(pageNumber, $index)"  ng-class="{'active' :pagination.current == pageNumber, 'disabled' : pageNumber == '...' }">
    <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pageNumber)">{{ pageNumber }}</a>
</li>
```

and in your css

```
.active{
    background-color:#000; // Enter your color Code or name
}
```

Comment: why u r duplicating the answer

Comment: I have not copied your answer . you edited your answer . before few minutes .